# Recommended browsers/search engines which prevent tracking of search terms (NB: not anonymous browsing)

Tags: web-browser, privacy, search-engine, tracking

Can anyone suggest a browser or search engine which allows web searches without the terms being indexed somewhere by the engine?

Right off the bat let me say I don't care about anonymous searching. I'm aware of all sorts of privacy enhancements and alternatives to Chrome which ensure you don't get your personal data connected to the search terms you place. That's great - but I'm not searching for child porn or anything illegal on the dark net. In fact, if anything, I'd prefer to have my name/details linked with my search terms.

What I mean is this: Say I'm a scientist working at a startup and I'm making use of the internet to search for novel techniques of jet propulsion so I might have a search like the following: "jet propulsion +[myBrightIdea]" where I don't want [myBrightIdea] (or for that matter, any) terms of my search being indexed such as would happen with the regular feeds that might go get aggregated into Google's Trending Now service. I would like to be able to research my ideas without putting my competitors on my trail (throw them off my scent, so to speak). Is there any reliable way of doing this?

I'm not convinced anonymous searching is the answer as just because you might get your details kept private/hidden/not connected to the search you're performing doesn't mean the search terms **themselves** don't get collected/indexed/aggregated somewhere. Or am I mistaken and does use of anonymous search engines hit two birds with one stone, so-to-speak?

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: I can't see a browser doing that. I think you would be best off with a web crawler.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the Search Engine https://duckduckgo.com ?

Here is their privacy page of what data they collect and don't collect: https://duckduckgo.com/privacy